.NET8 Blazor web app - All Identity pages redirect to 404 after short pause
I have a .NET8 Blazor web app, which I created without including Identity (long story why, not relevant now). I spent many hours getting the design right, and then realised that I needed Identify after all.
I created a new web app, including Identity, and copied the relevant files over to my existing project (adjusting namespaces to suit). I then added a migration, and updated the database.
The non-Identity parts of the app work fine, as they did before, but if I navigate to any of the Identity pages, such as /Account/Register, then I see the correct content for a few seconds, and then I get a plain white page with the words "Not found" at the top left.
As far as I can see, this is the default 404 behaviour. I added a Blazor component named OopsWrongUrl.razor (heck, I was over-tired and frustrated by the time I named it!) and updated Routes.razor to look like this...
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
  <Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)">
      <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectToLogin />
      </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeRouteView>
  </Found>
  <NotFound>
    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
      <OopsWrongUrl />
    </LayoutView>
  </NotFound>
</Router>

Now when I navigate to an Identity page, I see my hand-crafted 404 page, so it does look like it's redirecting. However, I can't work out why it's doing this, nor where the redirection is happening. The only place in all the Identity stuff where I can see any navigating happening is in IdentityRedirectManager. However, I added breakpoints inside every method in there, and none of them were hit, so I don't think it's that.
This issue happens on every single Identity page, so it's not specific to any of the individual pages. It doesn't happen on any non-Identity pages.
I injected a NavigationManager into my 404 page, and used it to show the URL. This came up as http://localhost:5276/Account/Login. Not sure if this helps, as that's what the browser's address bar shows, ad matches the first line of Login.razor (which is the page I'm trying right now)...
@page "/Account/Login"

Not sure if this helps.
Update: Following the comment by Brian Parker, I tried adding the following at the top of the Login.razor file...
@rendermode InteractiveServer

...but the issue remains the same.
I realise I haven't shown much code, but the bit I showed above is basically the only code I've changed from what the template supplied.
Anyone able to help? I just don't know where to look.
The solution
Thanks to Brian Parker, I did some more digging and discovered that the template's App.razor contained the following...
  [CascadingParameter]
  private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

  private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage =>
    HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
      ? null
      : InteractiveAuto;

This was then used in the markup...
<head>
  ... other stuff
  <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>
<body>
  <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
  ... other stuff
</body>

When I copied the files over, I didn't copy App.razor as I had modified it quite a lot, and so I didn't notice this extra code.
Along with the @rendermode InteractiveServer line in each Identity page, this (almost) fixed my problems. Not sure why the render mode is set to null when on Identity pages. I tried setting it to InteractiveServer but the problem persisted with that.
I also found that I got a NRE in a few places (such as in OnInitializedAsync in Login.razor) where the HttpContext was null. Not sure why that would be, but changing the code to HttpContext?.Request fixed the problem.
So, thanks to Brian I'm sorted, but I would like to know..

Why only null works for the render mode on Identity pages, whereas InteractiveServer (which is what I need to set on each Identity page) doesn't work
Why I was getting a null HttpContext and if using ?. is going to cause any problems.

Thanks for all the help

Have you looked in the logs to see if there's anything there that might give a clue?

@AvrohomYisroel Yes, I set logging to trace, which produced hundreds of lines of output, but I couldn't see anything that looked remotely relevant. Thanks

This is a rendermode issue. Auth pages should remain largely SSR. They don't exist on the client, so if you have changed the rendermode, when blazor trys to switch to wasm the pages dont exist.

Does the new web application (including Identity) render in the same way as the existing .NET8 Blazor web application? You can check if the Identity service is configured correctly in Program.cs and if there are any redirects or error responses when accessing the Identity page in the browser developer tools.

@BrianParker I tried changing the render mode (see my updated question), but it didn't help. Please can you check I did it right. Thanks.

When you say you copied them over what render modes are in program.cs vs source etc? The Auth pages are designed for SSR using Antiforgery tokens.

Auth pages are not interactive they post "forms".

@BrianParker Please see my updated question. With your help I got it working, but am still not clear about a couple of points. Thanks again for the help
